# Is it possible to populate a const QHash (or similar) before class initialization?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I'm trying to do something like an error manager class, linking enum values to strings and other things non important.

When I was coding, I stopped on something that made me curious if is that possible. The way I was doing, my class has a QHash object which will be populated on constructor:

```
class PrtsERrs {
private: 
    QHash<int, QString> err;
public:
    PrtsErrs() {
        err.insert(MyEnum::ZERO_VALUE, "zero");
        err.insert(MyEnum::ONE_VALUE, "one");
        ...
    }
}
```

But I thought it's "wrong", then I try to find something better or "right way" but I failed.

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
namespace Errs {
    enum Errs {
        ERR_TEST1 = 0,
        ERR_TEST2,
        ERR_TEST3
    };
}

class PrtsErrs {
private:
    const QHash<Errs::Errs, QString> errStr;
public:

    PrtsErrs() : errStr ({Errs::ERR_TEST1, "Test"},
                         {Errs::ERR_TEST2, "Test2"},
                         {Errs::ERR_TEST3, "Test3"}
                        ) {}

    QString errStr(Errs::Errs errCode) const { return errStr[errCode];}

};
```

Is possible to do something like that using c++11 and Qt? And if so, is it the best way?

Comment: Try with `errStr {{Errs::ERR_TEST1, "Test"},
                         {Errs::ERR_TEST2, "Test2"},
                         {Errs::ERR_TEST3, "Test3"}
                        }`

Comment: @MariusBancila not successful :/, but thanks! `error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const QHash<Errs::Errs, QString>*' in initialization`

Comment: What Qt version are you using? In Qt 5.5 `QHash` has a constructor that takes an `initializer_list`.

Comment: @MariusBancila oh, sry it works actually. Don't know why, but after I adapted my code for use `std::map`, I changed it to `QHash` again and it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++11 and higher, you can do something like the following (using classes from C++ standard library instead of `QHash` and `QString`; you can probably make it work with `QHash`/`QString` with some minor modifications):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

namespace Errs {
    enum Errs {
        ERR_TEST1 = 0,
        ERR_TEST2,
        ERR_TEST3
    };
}


class PrtsErrs {
private:
    const std::map<Errs::Errs, std::string> errStr {
        { Errs::Errs::ERR_TEST1, "ERR_TEST1" },
        { Errs::Errs::ERR_TEST2, "ERR_TEST2" },
        { Errs::Errs::ERR_TEST3, "ERR_TEST3" }
    };
public:
    std::string GetErrStr(Errs::Errs errCode) const 
    { 
        return errStr.at(errCode);
    }
} ;

int main() 
{
    PrtsErrs foo ; 
    std::cout << foo.GetErrStr(Errs::Errs::ERR_TEST2) << std::endl ;
    return 0;
}
```

You may try out the above code [here](http://ideone.com/wmX15H). However, instead of making a class to convert the enums to strings, I would [recommend making a non-member function](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197?pgno=1). Such as:

```
std::string errs_to_string(Errs::Errs errCode)
{
    static const std::map<Errs::Errs, std::string> errStr {
        { Errs::Errs::ERR_TEST1, "ERR_TEST1" },
        { Errs::Errs::ERR_TEST2, "ERR_TEST2" },
        { Errs::Errs::ERR_TEST3, "ERR_TEST3" }
    };
    return errStr.at(errCode) ;
}
```

Try out the above function [here](http://ideone.com/jxplin).

Comment: Oh, thanks! I'm going to study if a non-member function is the best for my case, but I think so. I report it to you later! :)